# split relative layout into two equal parts using linear layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout which contains two linear layouts. I want these two linear layouts to be placed in either halves of the relative layout containing them i.e. one to be positioned at top half and other at bottom half. Can anyone here help me with this. Here is the xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/updatedetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/oneeventbkg" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/Top_half_layout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/update_sn_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/update_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/update_message_pic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/update_sn_icon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/update_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/update_message_pic"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:maxHeight="400dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"            
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_half_layout">


        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" 
        android:id="@+id/toggle_after"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toggle_like_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="1000"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_like_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/xml_like_button_selctor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toggle_comment_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:text="100"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_comment_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"          
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/xml_comment_button_selector" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/likes_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/toggle_after"
            android:padding="20dp"
            />               

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/comments_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/toggle_after"
            android:padding="20dp" />



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/comments_list"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" 
            android:id="@+id/toggle_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/like_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="1000"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/like_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/xml_like_button_selctor" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:text="100"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/comment_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"          
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/xml_comment_button_selector" />

        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of using `RelativeLayout` use `LinearLayout` that's more easy to split

Comment: You can't use the layout_weight parameters on a RelativeLayout. These are parameters from the LinearLayout.

Comment: Make LinearLayout as your parent. Hope it will work as you want. Otherwise use nested LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/updatedetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/oneeventbkg" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/Top_half_layout">

        // Your Codes

    </LinearLayout> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"            
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_half_layout">

         // Your Codes

    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/updatedetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/oneeventbkg" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/Top_half_layout">

        // Your Codes

    </RelativeLayout> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"            
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_half_layout">

         // Your Codes

    </RelativeLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have to make use of relative layout inorder to place of the controls at proper position. can you tell me how to do it using relative layout?

Comment: Or what if I use two Relative Layouts Inside a Linear Layout? will it be possible to split linear layout into two equal parts?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it?. Split a linear layout into two halves using two relative layouts.

Comment: @Badrul See i edited. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765170/android-relativelayout-equal-spacing

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/updatedetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/oneeventbkg" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/Top_half_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/update_sn_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/update_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/update_message_pic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/update_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:maxHeight="400dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_half_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/toggle_after"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toggle_like_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="1000"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/toggle_like_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/xml_like_button_selctor" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toggle_comment_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:text="100"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/toggle_comment_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/xml_comment_button_selector" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/likes_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:padding="20dp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/comments_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:padding="20dp" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/toggle_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/like_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="1000"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/like_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/xml_like_button_selctor" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/comment_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:text="100"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/comment_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/xml_comment_button_selector" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```